# How to hide Angular Material mdToast?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toast

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $mdToast) 
{   
    $scope.showHideToast = function () {
        $mdToast.show({
                template: '<md-toast>test</md-toast>',
                hideDelay: 0,
                position: 'bottom right'
          });

        // DO STUFF

        $mdToast.hide();
}
```

The toast is showing up but not hiding.
I get this typeError:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.onRemove (../angular-material/angular-material.js:4240:13)
at Object.InterimElement.self.remove (../angular-material/angular-material.js:5103:29) 
at Object.hide (../angular-material/angular-material.js:5032:40)
...
```

Why is this not working in Angular Material? 
Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 7):

The real problem is how you are using the `hide` method, it can optionally receive in input a promise to be resolved.

So your code in order to work should be:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $mdToast) 
{   
    $scope.showHideToast = function () {
        // hold the reference
        var myToast = $mdToast.show({
                        template  : '<md-toast>test</md-toast>',
                        hideDelay : 0,
                        position  : 'bottom right'
                      });

        // DO STUFF

        // hide the toast
        $mdToast.hide(myToast);
   };
}
```

Calling the `hide` method in this way closes the previously defined toast, even if it was defined with `hideDelay: 0`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the answer above was down-voted. If you set hideDelay to 0, it won't hide the toast as I have experienced it. I had this issue too but my own case was a comma after the last property's value which happen to be the hideDelay property.

I suggest you set a value higher than zero and doing that, I don't think you will need to call `$mdToast.hide()` again.

Doing this just works fine for me:

```
$mdToast.show({
  template: '<md-toast class="md-warn">Test</md-toast>',
  hideDelay: 2000
});
```

It shows the toast message and hides it after 2seconds

EDIT:

Also, consider checking the version of your hammerjs any version above 2.0.0 should be fine IMO

Answer (score 0):

You've set hideDelay to 0.  I recommend setting it to 6000.  0 means never hide.