# AngularJS $mdToast doesn't hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am building a web application that uses an AngularJS and Angular Material frontend. I want to use $mdToast as notifications on errors.

I have the following code in my main application controller (AppCtrl):

```
$rootScope.$on('httpError', function (event, errorMessage) {
  $mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
    .textContent(errorMessage.message)
    .position('top right')
    .hideDelay(3000)
);
});
```

But somehow the toast doesn't hide after the hideDelay expires when the error is triggered in another $scope.

Does someone know how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine for me. I didn't try broadcasting the event from another scope. You can try using a `$timeout` to hide the dialog instead of the `hideDelay()` function like I did in [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dWZBcyLW13qNvhufOiHH).

The updated code would look something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('httpError', function (event, errorMessage) {
  $mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
    .textContent(errorMessage.message)
    .position('top right')
  );
  $timeout(function() {
    $mdToast.hide();
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer worsnupd. I can see that the $timout is triggered using a console.log() in the anonymous function, however the $mdToast.hide() doesn't seem to do anything to the toast that is being shown.. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried storing a reference to the toast you created and then calling `hide()` on that reference? This method is discussed in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927747/how-to-hide-angular-material-mdtoast).

Comment: Also, depending on the version of Angular Material you are using, you may be experiencing a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/650) from some time ago. You can try updating to a more recent version to see if that fixes the problem.